# How to scale alpha values in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What's the best way to scale alpha values in a canvas?

The first problem I'm trying to solve is drawing a sprite that has intrinsic low alpha values. I want to draw it 3-4 times brighter than it really is. Currently I'm just drawing it 4 times in the same spot. (I cannot edit the image file and `globalAlpha` doesn't go above 1)

The second problem I'm trying to solve is drawing the boundary of multiple overlapping sprites. The sprites are circular but with squiggles. I figured I'd use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490336/2118) combined with `globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'`, but for that I need to maximize the alpha values for the second drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option to markE's answer - you can simply scale the alpha channel directly.

I would only recommend this approach as a part of a pre-processing stage and not for use every time you need to use a sprite as iterating the buffer this way is a relatively slow process.

**[LIVE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/k9e2T/)**

[image: snapshot from demo]

Assuming you already have the sprite in a canvas and know its position:

```
/// get the image data and cache its pixel buffer and length
var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
var data = imageData.data;
var length = data.length;
var i = 0;

var scale = 4; /// scale values 4 times. This may be a fractional value

/// scale only alpha channel
for(; i < length; i += 4) {
    data[i + 3] *= scale;
}

context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
```

The good thing with the `Uint8ClampedArray` which the canvas is using clamps and rounds the values for you so you do not need to check lower or upper bounds, nor convert the value to integer - the internal code do all this *for* you.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because it's what I ended up using. As you mention it has terrible efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can "brighten" an rgba color by flattening it to rgb and then increasing the rgb component values.

- Convert the rgba value to rgb, also taking the background color into effect.
- Increase the resulting red,green,blue values by a percentage to "brighten" the color.

Here's a function to do that (disclaimer: untested code here!):

```
function brighten(RGBA,bg,pct){

  // convert rgba to rgb

  alpha = 1 - RGBA.alpha/255;
  red = Math.round((RGBA.alpha*(RGBA.red/255)+(alpha*(bg.red/255)))*255);
  green = Math.round((RGBA.alpha*(RGBA.green/255)+(alpha*(bg.green/255)))*255);
  blue = Math.round((RGBA.alpha*(RGBA.blue/255)+(alpha*(bg.blue/255)))*255);

  // brighten the flattened rgb by a percentage (100 will leave the rgb unaltered)

  redBright=parseInt(  Math.min(255,red*pct/100) );
  greenBright=parseInt(  Math.min(255,green*pct/100) );
  blueBright=parseInt(  Math.min(255,blue*pct/100) );

  return({red:redBright,green:greenBright,blue:blueBright});

}
```